# Parameterized routes without using a forward slash in Angular 13

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, routes, angular13

I have a route like below in one of my lazy loading modules in my **Angular 13 app**. When running the application in the browser, I get the url like this, **https://localhost:44477/myroute-to-/colombo**.

I want to change the URL to an SEO friendly URL, so I want to remove the slash (/) before the parameter of the route, so that it will be like **https://localhost:44477/myroute-to-colombo**, **https://localhost:44477/myroute-to-kandy** etc.

```
path: 'myroute-to-/:city',
        component: MyDestinationComponent,
```

My backend is an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project. My requirement is not to use query parameters instead of route parameters. So I must use route parameters, and I have to remove this forward slash (/) from the URL using either a frontend or backend method.

Could someone please help me achieve this?

I tried so many things, but I was unable to find the solution. Below are a few of them I tried using Bard. I have added Bard's comments as well.

**Method 1:**

The following code shows how to create a custom URL matcher to remove the trailing slash:

```
function removeTrailingSlash(url: string): string {
  if (url.endsWith('/')) {
    return url.slice(0, -1);
  } else {
    return url;
  }
}
```

You can then use this custom URL matcher in your routing module like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'myroute-to-:city',
    matcher: removeTrailingSlash,
    component: MyDestinationComponent,
  }
];
```

This will tell the Angular router to remove the trailing slash from the URL before matching it against the route. This will allow you to get the dynamic path without a slash.

**Method 2:**

Here is an example of how to use a custom UrlMatcher to ignore the forward slash in the parameter name:

```
import { UrlMatcher } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyUrlMatcher implements UrlMatcher {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  match(url: string): Observable<RouteMatch> {
    if (url.startsWith('product:')) {
      return this.router.match(url.slice(8));
    }

    return Observable.empty();
  }

}
```

This custom UrlMatcher will match the route path product:id to the URL /product/id. However, this is a more complex solution and is not recommended.

**Method 3:**

URL rewriting techniques on the server side.

Angular 13 App

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-detail',
  templateUrl: './product-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-detail.component.css']
})
export class ProductDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  }

}
```

ASP.NET Core Web API 6

```
[Route('api/products/{id}')]
public async Task<Product> GetProduct(int id) {
  return await _productRepository.GetProduct(id);
}

[Route('api/products/:slug')]
public async Task<Product> GetProductBySlug(string slug) {
  return await _productRepository.GetProductBySlug(slug);
}
```

```
app.UseUrlRewriter(routes => {
  routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: 'product-by-slug',
    routeTemplate: 'api/products/{slug}',
    defaults: new { controller = 'Products', action = 'GetProductBySlug' }
  );
});
```

I cannot go for Method 3 because, currently, I don't have two endpoints in my backend to rewrite one to another.